# How to break up a nested json file

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I'm getting data from an api which has a nested Json file. I write the file and it creates like this:

```
{"country": "Afghanistan", "timeline": [{"total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]}
{"country": "Albania", "timeline": [{"total": 2883079, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]}
{"country": "Algeria", "timeline": [{"total": 15205854, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]}
```

issue I'm facing is that I need to break up 'timeline' and leave me with just total, daily and date so that it looks more like this:-

```
{"country": "Afghanistan", "total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}
{"country": "Albania", "total": 2883079, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}
{"country": "Algeria", "total": 15205854, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}
```

I've tried json_normalise which didn't work so I'm wondering what is going wrong. The code is:-

```
def get_country_vaccines(self, last_days: int = 3, full_data = 'true') -> requests.Response:
    return requests.get(self.host + 'vaccine/coverage/countries', params={'lastdays': last_days, 'fullData': full_data})

class VaccineData(CovidBase):
    __tablename__ = 'vaccination_data'


base_value = Column(Integer, primary_key= True)
country = Column(String)
timeline = Column(JSON)

@classmethod
def from_requests(cls, request: dict):
    
    return cls(
        country=request.get('country'),
        timeline = request.get('timeline') 
    )

def to_bigquery_row(self):
    return {
        'country': self.country,
        'timeline': self.timeline,
    }

with open('covidinfo.json','w') as newfile:
    response = get_country_vaccines('1')
    for item in response.json():
        data = sq_models.VaccineData.from_requests(item)
        newfile.write(json.dumps(data.to_bigquery_row()))
        newfile.write('\n')

    input(data)
```

How could I break up the information in timeline so that each field inside it is now separate? Sorry I'm fairly new to python so just looking for some help with this.

Comment: The `timeline` array always contains only a single dict or it may happen that for some response it has multiple entries?

Comment: It should always have have one entry for each category

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse the original `JSON` data as a Python dictionary:

```
d = {"country": "Afghanistan", "timeline": [{"total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]}

d1 = {"country":d["country"]}
for i in d["timeline"][0].keys():
    d1[i] = d["timeline"][0][i]
print(d1)
```

**Output:** *The final transformed dict would look like this*

```
{'country': 'Afghanistan', 'total': 6355931, 'daily': 0, 'totalPerHundred': 0, 'dailyPerMillion': 0, 'date': '6/24/22'}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. Since I'm writing a new json file with the values, should d be 'data' and then I use the for loop to get each value in 'timeline'?

Answer (score 1):

If you know your data structure well and you don't want to involve any magic, I'd just iterate over the original data and flatten the timeline entries.

One possible way to do it (assuming that the `timeline` array always holds a single element):

```py
nested_data = [
    {"country": "Afghanistan", "timeline": [{"total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]},
    {"country": "Albania", "timeline": [{"total": 2883079, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]},
    {"country": "Algeria", "timeline": [{"total": 15205854, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/24/22"}]}
]

flat_data = []

for nested_obj in nested_data:
  flat_obj = {}
  for key, value in nested_obj.items():
    if key == "timeline":
      for timeline_key, timeline_value in nested_obj[key][0].items():
        flat_obj[timeline_key] = timeline_value
    else:
      flat_obj[key] = value
  flat_data.append(flat_obj)

print(flat_data)
```

Comment: This seems to be working thank you! Would this work if we changed the dataset so that timeline had more values? The data is also in a json file so is there a way to make this change through the get functions? Example:-                                              {"country": "Afghanistan", "timeline": [{"total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/25/22"}, {"total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/26/22"}, {"total": 6355931, "daily": 0, "totalPerHundred": 0, "dailyPerMillion": 0, "date": "6/27/22"}]}

Comment: @zaphyro it wouldn't break in that case either, only it would take into account the first entry in the `timeline` array. However it is possible to aggregate multiple timeline entries, but I don't know how would you like to approach that problem, do you need the sum of all, the average, or create as many flattened objects as many timeline dates you have?

Comment: The ideal option would be to to map each date in timeline to its total and daily value. What should I put as the value for nested_data if I need to do that for hundreds of entries? Sorry about the questions if they seem basic.

Comment: @zaphyro the best would be to update your sample input and the expected output in your original question, so the answers could align with those requirements.

Comment: Ah I see. I think I got it to work now without needing to unnest it but I'll update it after I've finished it up. Thank you for the help though, it will be useful for sure later on!